# Query using window functions

Tags: mysql, window-functions

```
create table hr
(
    candidate_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, -- candidate unique identifier
    candidate_gname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, -- candidate's given name
    candidate_fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, -- candidate's family name
    position VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, -- job position the candidate applied for
    hired BOOLEAN NOT NULL, -- final hiring decision (yes/no)
    zipcode CHAR(5) NOT NULL, -- hiring office zipcode
    population CHAR(2) NOT NULL -- candidate's membership to the
    -- "general" population (GP) or to the
    -- "protected" population (PP)
);
```

ex1)
Does membership to the “protected” population affect the chances of a random candidate of being hired? Write a SQL query to compute the relative frequency of positive and negative hiring decisions with respect to the two populations (“PP” and “GP”).

Below is the query I have written using window function,
But the freq should sum up to 1 wrt to population but my query is summing up to 1 considering the whole.
What changes chan I make ??
expected result:

| freq | hired | population |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.49 | true | GP |
| 0.51 | false | GP |
| 0.52 | true | PP |
| 0.48 | false | PP |

Query I have written:

```
Select round((avg(freq1)/5000),2) as freq,hired,population
From (Select population,hired,count(hired) 
        over (partition by population, hired) as freq1
        From hr
    ) as hr1
Group by population,hired
Order by population, hired desc;
```

result of the query:

```
freq | hired | population 
------+-------+------------
 0.15 | t     | GP
 0.45 | f     | GP
 0.06 | t     | PP
 0.34 | f     | PP
(4 rows)
```

Comment: WRT to population??

Comment: Yes, each population freq to should sum up to 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the population (bad name by the way) population rather than dividing by 5000

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(population varchar(2),hired varchar(5));

insert into t values
('pp','true'),('pp','true'),('pp','false'),('pp','true'),('pp','false'),
('gp','true'),('gp','true'),('gp','false'),('gp','true'),('gp','false');

Select round((avg(freq1))/popcount,2) as freq,hired,population
From (Select population,hired,
      count(hired) over (partition by population, hired) as freq1,
      count(hired) over (partition by population) as popcount
        From t hr
    ) as hr1
Group by population,hired
Order by population, hired desc;

'0.60', 'true', 'gp'
'0.40', 'false', 'gp'
'0.60', 'true', 'pp'
'0.40', 'false', 'pp'
```